# R: Barplots for visualization relation between dependent and independent variables

Tags: r, time-series, bar-chart, linear-regression, boxplot

I have a done a regression model and I am trying to produce similar plots as this one (Leitinger et al., 2008):

[image]

Here you can see the following important traits:

1. on y-axis you see the continuous dependent variable
2. on x-axis we have several ranges of the independent variable based on continuous data
3. N is the sample size
4. Legend describes some conditions

My data looks like this:

```
    fl_mean     snowheight_mean_sma
780 0.68033333  60.08055556
781 1.04666667  59.58611111
782 1.25600000  78.96527778
783 0.99433333  71.81944444
784 1.15133333  60.07986111
785 1.09900000  72.18263889
786 1.25600000  76.76388889
787 1.09900000  70.00972222
788 0.88966667  71.34166667
789 1.51766667  67.62847222
790 1.09900000  70.12847222
...
```

where "fl_mean" is the dependent variable and "snowheight_mean_sma" is the independent variable. I  have tried `geom_col`, `geom_bar` and `geom_boxplot` but without success. Googling for   such bar chart visualization of regression pairs was also without any result. Since my original data has NA gaps, as well as some seasonality to it I prefer to actually provide a `dput()` instead of randomly generated reproducible example. Here is the `dput()`: https://pastebin.com/i2AmVBei

Do you think I need to create a column of the ranges (categories) of the independent variable by myself and then based on it to calculate the average for these ranges for each datapoint or there is some automatic way to produce such graph? Let me know if I need to provide you some more data.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the `cut` and the `tapply` functions. The former is the tool to categorize data, the latter to do group-wise calculations. For the plot use the `barplot` function, where you may read the documentation `help(barplot)` on how to adjust colors, add labels, legends etc.

```
dat <- transform(dat, snow=cut(dat$snowheight_mean_sma, c(50, 60, 70, 80),
                               labels=c('< 60', '60 - 69', '70 - 80')))

barplot(with(dat, tapply(fl_mean, list(snow), sum)))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(fl_mean = c(0.68033333, 1.04666667, 1.256, 0.99433333, 
1.15133333, 1.099, 1.256, 1.099, 0.88966667, 1.51766667, 1.099
), snowheight_mean_sma = c(60.08055556, 59.58611111, 78.96527778, 
71.81944444, 60.07986111, 72.18263889, 76.76388889, 70.00972222, 
71.34166667, 67.62847222, 70.12847222)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("780", 
"781", "782", "783", "784", "785", "786", "787", "788", "789", 
"790"))
```